# Change mousewheel scroll rate in emacs console mode

Tags: emacs, scroll, mousewheel, konsole

Currently, when I use the mousewheel in emacs -nw mode, it skips two lines and then jumps to put the current line in the middle of the screen when the cursor gets to the bottom of the window.

What I want is for the cursor to jump one line at a time with mousewheel scrolling (so I can visit every line just with mouse scrolling), and only move the buffer down a single line when I scroll to the bottom of the screen.

I've gone in the Mouse options of emacs and set the "Mouse wheel scroll amount" to 1, along with "Mouse Wheel Progressive Speed" to 'off', but to no avail.

Is the "three line jump" behavior even contained in Emacs when I'm running in console mode?  I set my local machine's "scroll by" option to 1 line, but no help.  I don't see an option in the konsole (I'm using kubuntu) to change the mouse scrolling rate . . .